# Expand and collapse animation of custom Expandable list view in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-animation

I need sample code to make expand and collapse of custom expandable list view at same time?

expand and collapse should happen same time, with same speed?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "please share ans as early as possible" lol.... did you try to research before ask here ??

Comment: Kristiyan.....i have tried almost all solutions and then i asked question...

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class AnimatedExpandableListView extends ExpandableListView {
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final String TAG = AnimatedExpandableListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

/**
 * The duration of the expand/collapse animations
 */
private static final int ANIMATION_DURATION = 300;

private AnimatedExpandableListAdapter adapter;

public AnimatedExpandableListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public AnimatedExpandableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public AnimatedExpandableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

/**
 * @see ExpandableListView#setAdapter(ExpandableListAdapter)
 */
public void setAdapter(ExpandableListAdapter adapter) {
    super.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Make sure that the adapter extends AnimatedExpandableListAdapter
    if(adapter instanceof AnimatedExpandableListAdapter) {
        this.adapter = (AnimatedExpandableListAdapter) adapter;
        this.adapter.setParent(this);
    } else {
        throw new ClassCastException(adapter.toString() + " must implement AnimatedExpandableListAdapter");
    }
}

/**
 * Expands the given group with an animation.
 * @param groupPos The position of the group to expand
 * @return  Returns true if the group was expanded. False if the group was
 *          already expanded.
 */
@SuppressLint("NewApi") 
public boolean expandGroupWithAnimation(int groupPos) {
    boolean lastGroup = groupPos == adapter.getGroupCount() - 1;
    if (lastGroup && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        return expandGroup(groupPos, true);
    }

    int groupFlatPos = getFlatListPosition(getPackedPositionForGroup(groupPos));
    if (groupFlatPos != -1) {
        int childIndex = groupFlatPos - getFirstVisiblePosition();
        if (childIndex < getChildCount()) {
            // Get the view for the group is it is on screen...
            View v = getChildAt(childIndex);
            if (v.getBottom() >= getBottom()) {
                // If the user is not going to be able to see the animation
                // we just expand the group without an animation.
                // This resolves the case where getChildView will not be
                // called if the children of the group is not on screen

                // We need to notify the adapter that the group was expanded
                // without it's knowledge
                adapter.notifyGroupExpanded(groupPos);
                return expandGroup(groupPos);
            }
        }
    }

    // Let the adapter know that we are starting the animation...
    adapter.startExpandAnimation(groupPos, 0);
    // Finally call expandGroup (note that expandGroup will call
    // notifyDataSetChanged so we don't need to)
    return expandGroup(groupPos);
}

/**
 * Collapses the given group with an animation.
 * @param groupPos The position of the group to collapse
 * @return  Returns true if the group was collapsed. False if the group was
 *          already collapsed.
 */
public boolean collapseGroupWithAnimation(int groupPos) {
    int groupFlatPos = getFlatListPosition(getPackedPositionForGroup(groupPos));
    if (groupFlatPos != -1) {
        int childIndex = groupFlatPos - getFirstVisiblePosition();
        if (childIndex >= 0 && childIndex < getChildCount()) {
            // Get the view for the group is it is on screen...
            View v = getChildAt(childIndex);
            if (v.getBottom() >= getBottom()) {
                // If the user is not going to be able to see the animation
                // we just collapse the group without an animation.
                // This resolves the case where getChildView will not be
                // called if the children of the group is not on screen
                return collapseGroup(groupPos);
            }
        } else {
            // If the group is offscreen, we can just collapse it without an
            // animation...
            return collapseGroup(groupPos);
        }
    }

    // Get the position of the firstChild visible from the top of the screen
    long packedPos = getExpandableListPosition(getFirstVisiblePosition());
    int firstChildPos = getPackedPositionChild(packedPos);
    int firstGroupPos = getPackedPositionGroup(packedPos);

    // If the first visible view on the screen is a child view AND it's a
    // child of the group we are trying to collapse, then set that
    // as the first child position of the group... see
    // {@link #startCollapseAnimation(int, int)} for why this is necessary
    firstChildPos = firstChildPos == -1 || firstGroupPos != groupPos ? 0 : firstChildPos;

    // Let the adapter know that we are going to start animating the
    // collapse animation.
    adapter.startCollapseAnimation(groupPos, firstChildPos);

    // Force the listview to refresh it's views
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return isGroupExpanded(groupPos);
}

private int getAnimationDuration() {
    return ANIMATION_DURATION;
}

/**
 * Used for holding information regarding the group.
 */
private static class GroupInfo {
    boolean animating = false;
    boolean expanding = false;
    int firstChildPosition;

    /**
     * This variable contains the last known height value of the dummy view.
     * We save this information so that if the user collapses a group
     * before it fully expands, the collapse animation will start from the
     * CURRENT height of the dummy view and not from the full expanded
     * height.
     */
    int dummyHeight = -1;
}

/**
 * A specialized adapter for use with the AnimatedExpandableListView. All
 * adapters used with AnimatedExpandableListView MUST extend this class.
 */
public static abstract class AnimatedExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private SparseArray<GroupInfo> groupInfo = new SparseArray<GroupInfo>();
    private AnimatedExpandableListView parent;

    private static final int STATE_IDLE = 0;
    private static final int STATE_EXPANDING = 1;
    private static final int STATE_COLLAPSING = 2;

    private void setParent(AnimatedExpandableListView parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public int getRealChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    public int getRealChildTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    public abstract View getRealChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent);
    public abstract int getRealChildrenCount(int groupPosition);

    private GroupInfo getGroupInfo(int groupPosition) {
        GroupInfo info = groupInfo.get(groupPosition);
        if (info == null) {
            info = new GroupInfo();
            groupInfo.put(groupPosition, info);
        }
        return info;
    }

    public void notifyGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        GroupInfo info = getGroupInfo(groupPosition);
        info.dummyHeight = -1;
    }

    private void startExpandAnimation(int groupPosition, int firstChildPosition) {
        GroupInfo info = getGroupInfo(groupPosition);
        info.animating = true;
        info.firstChildPosition = firstChildPosition;
        info.expanding = true;
    }

    private void startCollapseAnimation(int groupPosition, int firstChildPosition) {
        GroupInfo info = getGroupInfo(groupPosition);
        info.animating = true;
        info.firstChildPosition = firstChildPosition;
        info.expanding = false;
    }

    private void stopAnimation(int groupPosition) {
        GroupInfo info = getGroupInfo(groupPosition);
        info.animating = false;
    }

    /**
     * Override {@link #getRealChildType(int, int)} instead.
     */
    @Override
    public final int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        GroupInfo info = getGroupInfo(groupPosition);
        if (info.animating) {
            // If we are animating this group, then all of it's children
            // are going to be dummy views which we will say is type 0.
            return 0;
        } else {
            // If we are not animating this group, then we will add 1 to
            // the type it has so that no type id conflicts will occur
            // unless getRealChildType() returns MAX_INT
            return getRealChildType(groupPosition, childPosition) + 1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Override {@link #getRealChildTypeCount()} instead.
     */
    @Override
    public final int getChildTypeCount() {
        // Return 1 more than the childTypeCount to account for DummyView
        return getRealChildTypeCount() + 1;
    }

    protected ViewGroup.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
        return new AbsListView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Override {@link #getChildView(int, int, boolean, View, ViewGroup)} instead.
     */
    @Override
    public final View getChildView(final int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final GroupInfo info = getGroupInfo(groupPosition);

        if (info.animating) {
            // If this group is animating, return the a DummyView...
            if (convertView instanceof DummyView == false) {
                convertView = new DummyView(parent.getContext());
                convertView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0));
            }
        if (childPosition < info.firstChildPosition) {
        convertView.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
                return convertView;
            }

            final ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView) parent;

            final DummyView dummyView = (DummyView) convertView;

            // Clear the views that the dummy view draws.
            dummyView.clearViews();

            // Set the style of the divider
            dummyView.setDivider(listView.getDivider(), parent.getMeasuredWidth(), listView.getDividerHeight());

            // Make measure specs to measure child views
            final int measureSpecW = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            final int measureSpecH = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

            int totalHeight = 0;
            int clipHeight = parent.getHeight();

            final int len = getRealChildrenCount(groupPosition);
            for (int i = info.firstChildPosition; i < len; i++) {
                View childView = getRealChildView(groupPosition, i, (i == len - 1), null, parent);

                LayoutParams p = (LayoutParams) childView.getLayoutParams();
                if (p == null) {
                    p = (AbsListView.LayoutParams) generateDefaultLayoutParams();
                    childView.setLayoutParams(p);
                }

                int lpHeight = p.height;

                int childHeightSpec;
                if (lpHeight > 0) {
                    childHeightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(lpHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                } else {
                    childHeightSpec = measureSpecH;
                }

                childView.measure(measureSpecW, childHeightSpec);
                totalHeight += childView.getMeasuredHeight();

                if (totalHeight < clipHeight) {
                    // we only need to draw enough views to fool the user...
                    dummyView.addFakeView(childView);
                } else {
                    dummyView.addFakeView(childView);

                    // if this group has too many views, we don't want to
                    // calculate the height of everything... just do a light
                    // approximation and break
                    int averageHeight = totalHeight / (i + 1);
                    totalHeight += (len - i - 1) * averageHeight;
                    break;
                }
            }

            Object o;
            int state = (o = dummyView.getTag()) == null ? STATE_IDLE : (Integer) o;

            if (info.expanding && state != STATE_EXPANDING) {
                ExpandAnimation ani = new ExpandAnimation(dummyView, 0, totalHeight, info);
                ani.setDuration(this.parent.getAnimationDuration());
                ani.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        stopAnimation(groupPosition);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        dummyView.setTag(STATE_IDLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

                });
                dummyView.startAnimation(ani);
                dummyView.setTag(STATE_EXPANDING);
            } else if (!info.expanding && state != STATE_COLLAPSING) {
                if (info.dummyHeight == -1) {
                    info.dummyHeight = totalHeight;
                }

                ExpandAnimation ani = new ExpandAnimation(dummyView, info.dummyHeight, 0, info);
                ani.setDuration(this.parent.getAnimationDuration());
                ani.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        stopAnimation(groupPosition);
                        listView.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        info.dummyHeight = -1;
                        dummyView.setTag(STATE_IDLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

                });
                dummyView.startAnimation(ani);
                dummyView.setTag(STATE_COLLAPSING);
            }

            return convertView;
        } else {
            return getRealChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, isLastChild, convertView, parent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        GroupInfo info = getGroupInfo(groupPosition);
        if (info.animating) {
            return info.firstChildPosition + 1;
        } else {
            return getRealChildrenCount(groupPosition);
        }
    }

}

private static class DummyView extends View {
    private List<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
    private Drawable divider;
    private int dividerWidth;
    private int dividerHeight;

    public DummyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setDivider(Drawable divider, int dividerWidth, int dividerHeight) {
        if(divider != null) {
            this.divider = divider;
            this.dividerWidth = dividerWidth;
            this.dividerHeight = dividerHeight;

            divider.setBounds(0, 0, dividerWidth, dividerHeight);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add a view for the DummyView to draw.
     * @param childView View to draw
     */
    public void addFakeView(View childView) {
        childView.layout(0, 0, getWidth(), childView.getMeasuredHeight());
        views.add(childView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        final int len = views.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            View v = views.get(i);
            v.layout(left, top, left + v.getMeasuredWidth(), top + v.getMeasuredHeight());
        }
    }

    public void clearViews() {
        views.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        if(divider != null) {
            divider.setBounds(0, 0, dividerWidth, dividerHeight);
        }

        final int len = views.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            View v = views.get(i);

            canvas.save();
            canvas.clipRect(0, 0, getWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
            v.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();

            if(divider != null) {
                divider.draw(canvas);
                canvas.translate(0, dividerHeight);
            }

            canvas.translate(0, v.getMeasuredHeight());
        }

        canvas.restore();
    }
}

private static class ExpandAnimation extends Animation {
    private int baseHeight;
    private int delta;
    private View view;
    private GroupInfo groupInfo;

    private ExpandAnimation(View v, int startHeight, int endHeight, GroupInfo info) {
        baseHeight = startHeight;
        delta = endHeight - startHeight;
        view = v;
        groupInfo = info;

        view.getLayoutParams().height = startHeight;
        view.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
        if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {
            int val = baseHeight + (int) (delta * interpolatedTime);
            view.getLayoutParams().height = val;
            groupInfo.dummyHeight = val;
            view.requestLayout();
        } else {
            int val = baseHeight + delta;
            view.getLayoutParams().height = val;
            groupInfo.dummyHeight = val;
            view.requestLayout();
        }
    }
}}
```

A detailed explanation for how this class works:

Animating the ExpandableListView was no easy task. The way that this
class does it is by exploiting how an ExpandableListView works.

Normally when {@link ExpandableListView#collapseGroup(int)} or
{@link ExpandableListView#expandGroup(int)} is called, the view toggles
the flag for a group and calls notifyDataSetChanged to cause the ListView
to refresh all of it's view. This time however, depending on whether a
group is expanded or collapsed, certain childViews will either be ignored
or added to the list.

Knowing this, we can come up with a way to animate our views. For
instance for group expansion, we tell the adapter to animate the
children of a certain group. We then expand the group which causes the
ExpandableListView to refresh all views on screen. The way that
ExpandableListView does this is by calling getView() in the adapter.

However since the adapter knows that we are animating a certain group,
instead of returning the real views for the children of the group being
animated, it will return a fake dummy view. This dummy view will then
draw the real child views within it's dispatchDraw function. The reason
we do this is so that we can animate all of it's children by simply
animating the dummy view. After we complete the animation, we tell the
adapter to stop animating the group and call notifyDataSetChanged. Now
the ExpandableListView is forced to refresh it's views again, except this
time, it will get the real views for the expanded group.

So, to list it all out, when {@link #expandGroupWithAnimation(int)} is
called the following happens:

1. The ExpandableListView tells the adapter to animate a certain group.
2. The ExpandableListView calls expandGroup.
3. ExpandGroup calls notifyDataSetChanged.
4. As an result, getChildView is called for expanding group.
5. Since the adapter is in "animating mode", it will return a dummy view.
6. This dummy view draws the actual children of the expanding group.
7. This dummy view's height is animated from 0 to it's expanded height.
8. Once the animation completes, the adapter is notified to stop
   animating the group and notifyDataSetChanged is called again.
9. This forces the ExpandableListView to refresh all of it's views again.
   10.This time when getChildView is called, it will return the actual
   child views.

For animating the collapse of a group is a bit more difficult since we
can't call collapseGroup from the start as it would just ignore the
child items, giving up no chance to do any sort of animation. Instead
what we have to do is play the animation first and call collapseGroup
after the animation is done.

So, to list it all out, when {@link #collapseGroupWithAnimation(int)} is
called the following happens:

1. The ExpandableListView tells the adapter to animate a certain group.
2. The ExpandableListView calls notifyDataSetChanged.
3. As an result, getChildView is called for expanding group.
4. Since the adapter is in "animating mode", it will return a dummy view.
5. This dummy view draws the actual children of the expanding group.
6. This dummy view's height is animated from it's current height to 0.
7. Once the animation completes, the adapter is notified to stop
   animating the group and notifyDataSetChanged is called again.
8. collapseGroup is finally called.
9. This forces the ExpandableListView to refresh all of it's views again.
   10.This time when the ListView will not get any of the child views for
   the collapsed group.

Comment: I have tried this code and this provides animation..                                     but if  initially i open item at position 0 and then i open item at position 2...now collapsing of item at position 0 and expanding of item at position 2 should happens parralally , at same time with same speed..? i am looking for this kind of animation...i  am stucked in this.. if possible share complete sample or link which will help me....